# CSS: Can I overwrite child-class with parent-class?

Tags: html, css

I would like to know if I can overwrite child-class styles with parent-class styles. This is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      .red {
        color: red;
      }

      .blue {
        color: blue;
      }

      .parent {
        border: 2px solid chocolate;

        /*this does not work*/
        color: green;
        color: green !important;
      }

      /*this also does not work*/
      body .parent {
        color: green;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button class="parent">
      <span class="red">H</span>
      <span class="blue">i</span>
    </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have found a similar question here. But that is not what I have in my mind.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73121465/override-child-class-css-with-parent-class-css][1]

Comment: hi you have to try  this    .parent > * { color: green !important; }    if you just want to apply it to span apply like this   .parent > span { color: green !important; }

Comment: To strictly answer the question: you can't (unless you slightly change the selector as suggested above)

Comment: You could define a stronger CSS selector ```span.red { color: inherit;}```. That would work.

Comment: You set the same color green for the same parent 3 times, what exactly do you want to overwrite?
if you mean you want to change the child style using parent class, then you should use parent:nth-child(n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

If an element has a `color` of its own, then nothing about the `color` of its parent element can change that.

It will only take on the colour of the parent element if it has `color: inherit`.

If you want to change the colour of the elements with `class="red"` or `class="blue"` then you need a selector that selects *those* elements.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you could define a stronger CSS selector span.red { color: inherit;}. That would work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      .red {
        color: red;
      }

      .blue {
        color: blue;
      }

      .parent {
        border: 2px solid chocolate;
        color: green;
      }

      .parent span.red,
      .parent span.blue {
        color: inherit;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button class="parent">
      <span class="red">H</span>
      <span class="blue">i</span>
    </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can specify a child element:

```
.parent > *
```

Or refer to the tag

```
.parent span
```

Or you can set child color and it takes parent value:

```
color: inherit;
```

Or you can remove the color from your child element at all, so that it will take a parent color.